# Error reprocessing in Paperclip 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I updated from 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 for the string to array bug, and now when I try to call Model.image.reprocess! I get the following error. Is this something in my code or something in paperclip? Or maybe in the image I'm uploading?

```
"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/paperclip-2.3.5/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:134:in `to_file'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/paperclip-2.3.5/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:219:in `reprocess!'
/home/brian/Dropbox/portfolio/app/models/asset.rb:34:in `regenerate_styles!'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:77:in `invoke_job'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:118:in `block in run'
/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:117:in `run'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:176:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:102:in `block in work_off'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:101:in `times'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:101:in `work_off'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:75:in `block in start'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:72:in `loop'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:72:in `start'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/command.rb:100:in `run'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/command.rb:79:in `block in run_process'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:250:in `call'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:250:in `block in start_proc'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:199:in `call'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:199:in `call_as_daemon'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:254:in `start_proc'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:294:in `start'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:193:in `block in run_proc'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `call'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `catch_exceptions'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/command.rb:78:in `run_process'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/command.rb:72:in `block in daemonize'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/command.rb:70:in `times'
/home/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@sp/bundler/gems/delayed_job-aba9905764c2/lib/delayed/command.rb:70:in `daemonize'
script/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

Relevant model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :portfolio_item_id, :order

  belongs_to :portfolio_item

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => "20x20#",
      :small => "100x100",
      :large => "600x600>"
               },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV["S3_KEY"],
      :secret_access_key => ENV["S3_SECRET"]
                       },
    :bucket => ENV["S3_BUCKET"],
    :path => "portfolio/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  before_image_post_process do |image|
    if changed?
      processing = true
      false
    end
  end

  after_save do |image|
    if image.changed?
      send_later(:regenerate_styles!)
    end
  end

  def regenerate_styles!
    self.image.reprocess!
    self.processing = false
    self.save(false)
  end

  def changed?
    self.image_file_size_changed? ||
    self.image_file_name_changed? ||
    self.image_content_type_changed? ||
    self.image_update_at_changed?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/1fef4c302d076575a1ca9691e01eb96ee9262ebc#commitcomment-166132). Revert to the previous version and you'll be fine. This really had me pulling my hair out for a few days as well. :)

Comment: Hum. Is it fixed in the master branch? I may just have to check that out. It's not like anything is going to go wrong if I put a git repo in production code, right? ;)

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed 3 days ago actually so updating the gem should work. It taught me to specify a gem version the hard way as it frunked up my production application on heroku. :)

Comment: What version of the gem are you using? I'm on 2.3.5 and it's doing this to me.

Comment: Oh well this looks like a new bug. The to_file string to array bug was introduced in 2.3.4; 2.3.3 is working fine for me on rails 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just confirming I have the same issue. 
I'm on Rails 3 and have tried using Paperclip 2.3.5, 2.3.4 and 2.3.3 
All to no avail keep getting the same error as @Reactor5 when invoking reprocess

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I looked into this some more. It seems to be an issue with Paperclip and Ruby 1.9.2
Still don't know exactly what causes it, but switching to Ruby 1.8.7 solved the issue for me.