# Reprocessing S3 asset with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

**Background:**

I have implemented user-defined cropping on image uploads roughly as-per [Ryan Bates Railscast #182](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised).

This works when set to the `:file` storage method, but not when set to `:s3`. S3 storage was working fine before adding the intermediate cropping step.

From the server log, it appears to be looking for the source file locally:

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /profiles/pictures/000/001/543/original/headshot.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

This file is present on S3, but not locally by this point, as the upload is processed before being cropped (as well as after).

**My question:**

How can I bring the file down from S3 to the local server before the second process step?

*N.B. I have looked at other answers on SO already.*

[Paperclip looking for file locally for reprocessing when using S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121278/paperclip-looking-for-file-locally-for-reprocessing-when-using-s3) – seems relevant, but the only answer refers to downgrading Paperclip. I can’t do that, and besides, that answer is neither upvoted nor accepted.

[Error reprocessing in Paperclip 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055170/error-reprocessing-in-paperclip-2-3-5) – this is about an older version of Paperclip.

**Other thoughts:**

It has occurred to me that another approach would be to store the file locally until it has been cropped, and then use DelayedJob or something similar to upload it to S3 later on. This will be more work though, so I’d rather avoid it for now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to better understand what's happening, it would be cool to see your model set up. Specifically I'm looking for the "has_attached_file" setup.

Just to cover the basics of what I'm looking for: here's an example

```
 has_attached_file :picture,
                path: <optional, default is fine.>
                url: ':s3_alias_url',
                s3_protocol: 'https',
                s3_host_alias: 'cdn.<something>.com' (or, s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/,
                storage: :s3,
                s3_credentials: Proc.new{ |a| a.instance.credentials }
```

When you reprocess an image, it should be brought down into a temp file and processed there, then reuploaded with these settings.

based on the `profiles/pictures/000/001/543/original/headshot.jpg` it almost looks like it's grabbing your path variable, but not going to your s3 bucket to get that image. so I would check the storage value, specifically.

With more info, I can update my answer appropriately.

Comment: Hi, I actually switched everything over to Dragonfly some time ago! But looking in git, the original code was: `has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { ... }, :default_url => 'missing_:class_:attachment/missing_:style.png', :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => S3_CONFIG`

Comment: hmmm, A quick look through the Git for paperclip gave me these links.

This one describes a change in paperclip setting definitions:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1405

This one describes a similar issue but is from several years after this original post, and remains open. 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2217

That said, I believe I have gotten my images to reprocess (pull down from s3 and re-upload), so I'll try to follow this tutorial, build out the project, and update my answer.